# virtualenv isn't installed in PATH on OS X

Tags: python, virtualenv, homebrew

I have python 2.7.2 installed via homebrew on OS X 10.8.3. I installed virtualenv via `pip install virtualenv`.

When issue the command: `virtualenv venv`, I get this error: `-bash: virtualenv:command not found.`

FYI:

```
$ pip install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
$ ls /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
ls: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put /usr/local/bin into your PATH.

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

Comment: The answer is correct and now Homebrew installs python scripts into `$(brew --prefix)/bin`, too. For a few days, python scripts went into `$(brew --prefix)/share/python`, but no longer. Therefore, you may have to `brew reinstall python`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Michael Soulier's answer, you can add the path manually (for some reason this has always worked better for me).

`open ~/.bash_profile`

Paste in:

```
# Making usr/local the default lookup
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```